# constrained optimization without gradient

Tags: r, optimization

This is a more general question, somewhat independent of data, so I do not have a MWE.

I often have functions `fn(.)` that implement algorithms that are not differentiable but that I want to optimize. I usually use `optim(.)` with its standard method, which works fine for me in terms of speed and results.

However, I now have a problem that requires me to set bounds on one of the several parameters of `fn`. From what I understand, `optim(method="L-BFGS-B",...)` allows me to set limits to parameters but also requires a gradient. Because `fn(.)` is not a mathematical function but an algorithm, I suspect it does not have a gradient that I could derive through differentiation. This leads me to ask whether there is a way of performing constrained optimization in R in a way that does not require me to give a gradient.

I have looked at some sources, e.g. John C. Nash's texts on this topic but as far as I understand them, they concern mostly differentiable functions where gradients can be supplied.

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with providing no gradients and letting the solver do finite differences. A better way is to use a proper **derivative free optimization** (DFO) solver. An example is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dfoptim/dfoptim.pdf

Comment: As long as it is differentiable you don't need to actually supply the gradient. The `gr` argument of `optim` can be omitted.

Comment: you might also be able to re-parameterise things as a way of maintaining bounds.  e.g. optimising the log of something can be used to keep it positive

Comment: You can use perhaps genetic algorithm or differential evolution or any other evolutionary algorihtm.. those are black box optimizers, that do not require any property of the objective, only fitness value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comments so far (which are all things I would have said myself):

- you *can* use `method="L-BFGS-B"` without providing explicit gradients (the `gr` argument is optional); in that case, R will compute approximations to the derivative by finite differencing (@G.Grothendieck). It is the simplest solution, because it works "out of the box": you can try it and see if it works for you. However:

  - `L-BFGS-B` is probably the finickiest of the methods provided by `optim()` (e.g. it can't handle the case where a trial set of parameters evaluates to `NA`)
  - finite-difference approximations are *relatively* slow and numerically unstable (but, fine for simple problems)
- for simple cases you can fit the parameter on a transformed scale, e.g. if `b` is a parameter that must be positive, you can use `log_b` as a parameter (and transform it via `b <- exp(log_b)` in your objective function). (@SamMason) But:

  - there isn't always a simple transformation that will achieve the constraint you want
  - if the optimal solution is on the boundary, transforming will cause problems
- there are a variety of derivative-free optimizers with constraints (typically "box constraints", i.e. independent lower and/or upper bounds one or more parameters) (@ErwinKalvelagen): `dfoptim` has a few, I have used the `nloptr` package (and its BOBYQA optimizer) extensively, `minqa` has some as well. *This is the solution I would recommend.*

Comment: I am not so sure about some of those comments including speed, stability and numeric gradients. I have had good experiences with `optim` on many problems.